# how to remove searchbar.text characters not need in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to search by license plate but in the number plate " - & ." so i can not find the word i want to remove it

For example, 28b-0001.07 changes to 28b000107 in searchbar.text

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredCandies = listdevices.filter( { list -> Bool  in



            guard let text = searchBar.text else {return false}

            return list.devname.contains(text)

        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your no doing simple replacement string

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

 filteredCandies = listdevices.filter( { list -> Bool  in
 guard let text = searchBar.text else {return false}
 //Replace .- with ""
 let searchString = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "-.", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
return list.devname.contains(searchString)
    searchBar.text = searchString
   })
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```